# Allow string editing for complex classes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class I created to represent a time with just an hour and minutes called `Time`. I overloaded the `ToString()` method for that class. I'm displaying classes with `Time` properties in a DataGrid, using a `DataGridTextColumn` to show `Time`. Just watching works grate, but I can't edit it. I added to the time class a constructor that takes a string, no help. What do I need to implement in order for this to work?

The class Time:

```
public class Time
{

    public Time() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// the hour
    /// </summary>
    public int Hour
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// the minuets
    /// </summary>
    public int Minutes
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// the time in format hh:mm
    /// </summary>
    public string time
    {
        get { return String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", Hour, Minutes); }
        set 
        { 
            string[] spl = value.Split(':');
            Hour = Int32.Parse(spl[0]);
            Minutes = Int32.Parse(spl[1]);
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return time;
    }
}
```

There are also comparison operators, but I omitted them. (I don't think they matter much).

Comment: Why haven't you used `TimeSpan`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter three reasons - a. TimeSpan keeps more data than I need, b. easier to customize a class you write yourself, c. I wanted to get my hands dirty.

Comment: So by using a constructor, you are trying to create a new Time object, rather than editing the existing one? You will want to expose a Set method instead.

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson I guess the where is in the class `Time`, but how? I have a property that gets a string. I guess a operator= will be good, but you can't override it in c#.

Comment: Update your question with the code of your class

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel ...

Comment: The exact implementation depends on how your class is constructed. Like Plue said, seeing your class would help.

Comment: Steve B: Isn't reinventing the wheel how we all got started?

Comment: @SteveB Yhea... but you can't understand the car without inventing your own wheel.

Comment: What does your binding look like?

Comment: I would keep things (variables) as simple as possible until they are needed (ToString() gets called). Just forget about the "time" string and keep track of minutes and hours (or better yet, just minutes) internally. Then let the ToString() do something like { return minutes/60 + ":" + minutes%60;}

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson the point was the set of time, the get is just a bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like you need to use `CellStyle` formatting instead of overriding `ToString()`. But if you still want to *reinvent the wheel*, add property `Value` within `Time` and bind to it:

```
public class Time
{

    public Time() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// the hour
    /// </summary>
    public int Hour
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// the minuets
    /// </summary>
    public int Minutes
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// the time in format hh:mm
    /// </summary>
    public string Value
    {
        get { return String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", Hour, Minutes); }
        set 
        { 
            string[] spl = value.Split(':');
            Hour = Int32.Parse(spl[0]);
            Minutes = Int32.Parse(spl[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

And binding:

```
Text={Binding YourTimeProperty.Value, Mode=TwoWay}
```

Comment: The overriding of `ToString` is useful as it is. Also, why not to bind to `Time.time` property?

Comment: @elyashiv You can name it as you want until you'll read someone's code with properties starting with lowercase letter. And of course you can keep `ToString` override.